# Slow return from OpenCV's VideoCapture constructor on Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, computer-vision

I've recently been using a new Intel i9 Windows 11 workstation. When I run even a simple OpenCV C++ program, I find that the call to the `cv::VideoCapture` constructor can take 3-4 minutes to return; something like:

```
cv::VideoCapture vid_in(0);
```

After that, the program continues as expected. I have Windows' Camera "Let desktop apps access your camera" setting enabled; and my program is listed there. The camera is a Logitech Logi C270 HD WebCam. Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the delay?